# Retrieve Data From Database in C# and ASP.NET with buttonClick

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just need to know the code how button click could retrieve data from database in C# and ASP.NET to text box.

Comment: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1513/how-to-retrieve-data-from-the-database-in-aspnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using  MS SQL Try using ::

```
using System.Data.SQLClient;

Class DataExtract
{ 

Public DataTable Extract()
  {
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .;
                                       Initial Catalog = domain;
                                       Integrated Security = True");
     con.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tablename", con); 

     Return new DataTable().load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

  }
}
```

Comment: I just using text box to show data, not in the table.

Comment: just assign the value from desired column to the text box like ::

TextBox1.Text = Extract().Rows[RowNumber]["ColumnNameORIndex"].ToString();